# Explanation for this javascript syntax

Tags: javascript

Why does this work in JavaScript?

`undefined_variable_here: 2`
it returns 2 in the console

Then I tried this and it also worked
`{another_undefined_variable: 3}`

Is there a name or an explanation for this?

Comment: The last one is clearly legal. It simply initializes an object in JSON.

Comment: That's not true, because {a: 1, b: 2} throws an error!

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen it would be [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) when the identifier name was quoted. OPs code is just plain JavaScript

Comment: @LJ_1102 no, you are wrong. JSON means JavaScript Object Notation, and actually just refers to the notation used for representing objects. Sure, strings containing JSON are what JSON *serializers* accept, but that's not the point here.

Comment: @JadJoubran just because it didn't work in the console, doesn't mean it isn't valid JavaScript. But indeed, you did describe that it returned `2` in the console, which my code wouldn't.

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen thanks I know what JSON stands for hence i linked to the wikipedia article. Normally when referring to JSON people actually mean JSON as per the wikipedia definition as a: "*human-readable text to transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs*" and not the written out acronym...

Comment: Exactly. On that we agree. It was still valid JSON though, which is my point (quoted or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your first example is a labeled statement**: the expression "2" with the label "undefined_variable_here". Although JavaScript does not have a `goto` statement, there are still a few ways to jump to specific statements under certain circumstances. In order to do that, these statements need to have some kind of identifier attached, so that the machine knows where to go, and labels provide that identifier.

**Your second example is an object literal**: an expression for a single object which has one property called "another_undefined_variable" with the value 3.

**In both cases, semicolon insertion implicitly ends the statement**. So the first example is essentially equivalent to the statement:

```
2;
```

This statement isn't very useful by itself, because it doesn't do anything, but it *is* legal JavaScript. The second example actually does a little bit of work, in that it has to create the object, but because it doesn't get put into a variable, there are no references left: you can't get at it, and the garbage collector will wipe it out at the next opportunity. Still not very useful, but still legal.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! But then why adding another element would not work? Say: `{a: 2, b: 3}`

Answer (score 2):

You're basically creating a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). In the second case, even if it seems to you an object, you just surrounded the label by a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). In short, it's like you just typed "2" in both cases for the web console.